# Programming with dplyr using string as input

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to write a function that uses dplyr inside and I supply variable names as strings. Unfortunately dplyr-s use of NSE makes it rather complicated. From [Programming with dplyr](http://rpubs.com/hadley/dplyr-programming) I get the following example

```
my_summarise <- function(df, var) {
  var <- enquo(var)

  df %>%
    group_by(!!var) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
}

my_summarise(df, g1)
```

However, I would like to write function where instead of `g1` I could provide `"g1"` and I am not able to wrap my head around how to do that.

Comment: Just use `group_by_` instead of `group_by` and you don't need any of the `enquo` stuff.

Comment: I realize your example is taken from the doc you link (and seems to be written by an Authoritative Source), but I have to say it seems **terrible** to use `group_by` as the name of the argument that will get passed to the function of the same name.

Comment: It seems to be deprecated and I would like to understand how this should be done given the new model that hadley figured out

Comment: edited the `group_by` variable name out of the example

Comment: Read through the `lazyeval` package vignette or the [dplyr NSE vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html). But NSE is the default that requires all the quoting/formula stuff. If you want to use a string column name then that is standard evaluation, and you need to use the standard-evaluating functions that underly all the NSE counterparts, `group_by_`, `summarize_`, etc.

Comment: Again all the `*_` seem to be deprecated as of now and I would like to understand what is the right way to do this.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. That's disappointing, seems like it was just 2-3 years ago that `lazyeval` was new and was "the right way to do NSE", and I sort of knew what was going on.

Comment: @Gregor: When I looked at that webpage the variable name was initially `group_var` and then Hadley tried to dig himself out of the NSE hole that he created.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**dplyr >= 1.0**

Use combination of double braces and the across function:

```
my_summarise2 <- function(df, group_var) {
  df %>% group_by(across({{ group_var }})) %>% 
    summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}

my_summarise2(mtcars, "cyl")

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    cyl   mpg
#  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4  26.7
# 2     6  19.7
# 3     8  15.1

# same result as above, passing cyl without quotes
my_summarise(mtcars, cyl)
```

**dplyr < 1.0**

As far as I know, you could use `as.name` or `sym` (from the `rlang` package - I don't know if `dplyr` will import it eventually):

```
library(dplyr)
my_summarise <- function(df, var) {
  var <- rlang::sym(var)
  df %>%
    group_by(!!var) %>%
    summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}
```

or

```
my_summarise <- function(df, var) {
  var <- as.name(var)
  df %>%
    group_by(!!var) %>%
    summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}

my_summarise(mtcars, "cyl")
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#     cyl      mpg
#   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     4 26.66364
# 2     6 19.74286
# 3     8 15.10000
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `.data` pronoun from **rlang** is another option that works directly with column names stored as strings.

The function with `.data` would look like

```
my_summarise <- function(df, var) {
     df %>%
          group_by(.data[[var]]) %>%
          summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}

my_summarise(mtcars, "cyl")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl   mpg
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  26.7
2     6  19.7
3     8  15.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it using only `dplyr` and the very useful `as.name` function from base R:

```
my_summarise <- function(df, var) {
  varName <- as.name(var)
  enquo_varName <- enquo(varName)

  df %>%
    group_by(!!enquo_varName) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
}

my_summarise(df, "g1")
```

Basically, with `as.name()` we generate a name object that matches `var` (here `var` is a string). Then, following [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), we use `enquo()` to look at that name and return the associated value as a quosure. This quosure can then be unquoted inside the `group_by()` call using `!!`.