# Grouping on multiple programmatically specified vars in dplyr 0.6

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

This is with the new dplyr, to be released Real Soon Now.

The [dplyr programming vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) gives an example of calling `group_by` with the grouping variables specified in an outer function:

```
my_summarise <- function(df, group_var) {
  df %>%
    group_by(!!group_var) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
}
```

This works when supplied with a single grouping variable. However, it fails with multiple variables.

Simplified example:

```
f <- function(x)
{
    group_by(mtcars, !!x)
}

## works
g1 <- "cyl"
f(g1)

## doesn't work
#Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#  Column `c("cyl", "gear")` must be length 32 (the number of rows) or one, not 2
g2 <- c("cyl", "gear")
f(g2)
```

How can I fix this, within the rlang framework?

Ideally I want `f`'s signature to remain the same, ie I specify the grouping variables as a single vector rather than via a `...` argument.

Comment: Actually, `f(g1)` doesn't work as well. Try `f(g1) %>% summarize(n=n())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a pretty similar question: [Programming with dplyr using string as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121728/programming-with-dplyr-using-string-as-input). I just modified the answer a bit to use `syms` and `!!!`.

```
library(rlang)
f <- function(x){
  group_by(mtcars, !!!syms(x))
}

f(c("cyl")) %>% summarise(n())
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl `n()`
  <dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14

f(c("cyl", "gear")) %>% summarise(n())
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [?]
    cyl  gear `n()`
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     4     3     1
2     4     4     8
3     4     5     2
4     6     3     2
5     6     4     4
6     6     5     1
7     8     3    12
8     8     5     2
```