# Changing factors order inside a function

Tags: r

I have this function that generates a box plot:

```
generate_box <- function (df, x, y) {
  sort_order <- c("Strongly negative", "Negative", "Neutral", "Positive", "Strongly positive")
  gg <- df %>%
    mutate(x = factor(x, levels = sort_order)) %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 3, outlier.color = '#121212')
  return (gg)
}
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
plot <- generate_box(df, 'x_variable', 'y_variable')
```

The plot is generated successfully; however, the factors are NOT reordered.
I think the problem is the way I'm referencing the x variable. Because the same implementation worked outside the function in the global environment.

What should this line be for the function to work properly?

```
mutate(x = factor(x, levels = sort_order))
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a reproducible example?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72581622/pass-string-as-the-argument-in-function-to-be-used-in-other-function-in-r)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690702/pass-a-string-as-variable-name-in-dplyrmutate)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you! The second link has the answer! I wish there was a simpler way of programming with tidyverse.

Comment: @SevenSouls there's a simpler answer